# Magento 2 - How to make added checkout fields inline similar to the default checkout fields

Tags: magento2, checkout, css, uicomponent, fieldsets

I want to make the additional checkout fields imported from BSS OrderDeliveryDate extension, `date`, `time slot` and `special instructions` inline so that the styling matches the default checkout fields. Not sure what other changes are needed to do this.

These fields were added through a `Layout Processor Plugin`. Snippet here:

```
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
        ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children']['shipping_arrival_date'] = [
            'component' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/form/element/date',
                'options' => [],
                // 'disabled' => true,
                'id' => 'shipping-arrival-date',
                'class' => 'test'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.shipping_arrival_date',
            'label' => 'Delivery Date',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 200,
            'id' => 'shipping-arrival-date'
        ];
```

Here is a image of how the fields are rendered: 
[image]

Comment: Hi @KeyurShah, I know I can add a css/less file to style it, and I have been doing it to style the rest of the form. However, I found a that the html structure of the fields are similar and the classes and ids are identical as well, yet, the Pickup Details fields are not rendered in-line.

Comment: 'id' => 'shipping-arrival-date'
does this get picked up in css

Comment: did you get it working @Noemi

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to add new `XML` file in front-end layout directory with the name of `checkout_index_index.xml`

In this file you have write something like

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <head>
<css src="css/YOUR_NAME.css" />
</head>
</page>
```

In `YOUR_NAME.css` you can do your CSS magic with your requirement.

Comment: how does this work?

Comment: 'id' => 'shipping-arrival-date'
this is the id but it's not even getting picked up in FE